Which movie is this line from and what does it mean ("I thought it was a brothel, honest mistake")?
I recall a movie in which a man and woman are sword fighting and talking, in the dialog the woman says to the man "What were you doing in a Spanish nunnery anyway?".
To which he replies, "I thought it was a brothel, honest mistake".
What movie is this from and what does it mean?
Does it imply that Spanish women are sexually promiscuous (even comically)?

Pirates of the Caribbean: On Stranger Tides (2011)

Angelica: I was ready to take my vows. And you - what were you doing in a Spanish convent?!?
Jack Sparrow: I mistook it for a brothel. Honest mistake!

That dialogue was found as part of other dialogue from the movie here.
To the meaning, I guess that he's trying to explain his drunkenness as to being found in a convent, but who's to say that a pirate wouldn't use that angle regardless of the locale, or perhaps "back then" brothels and convents looked similar from the outside in some countries?

Not sure if the lingo was still in common usage, but in Elizabethan England, "nunnery" was sometimes used to mean brothel in slang.  So it could have been playing off that.

The line is a joke.
Usually it would be the other way around: a man caught in a brothel would deny responsibility by saying he thought the brothel was something completely innocuous, such as a nunnery. 
Jack flips this convention for comic effect.

Upvoted as its a better explanation, but answers are supposed to stand on their own, so you should include that it's from Stranger Tides.
